# AngularJs: Argument is not a function got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I started learning AngularJs so I started off this way by creating a view, service file and controller file separately as shown below:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ServicesTut.js"></script> 
<script src="ControllerTut.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">

            <div ng-controller="CalculatorController">
                Enter a number:
                <input type="number" ng-model="number">
                <button  ng-click="findSquare()">Square</button>
                <div>{{answer}}</div>
            </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my service file --- ServicesTut.js"

```
var CalculatorService = angular.module('CalculatorService', [])
app.service('Calculator', function () {
    this.square = function (a) { return a*a};

});
```

This is my controller file --- ControllerTut.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['CalculatorService']);
app.controller('CalculatorController', function ($scope, Calculator) {

    $scope.findSquare = function () {
        $scope.answer = Calculator.square($scope.number);
    }
});
```

On launching the code on my browser I get the following error message:

```
Error: Argument 'CalculatorController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Please assist me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `ServicesTut.js` you should be using `CalculatorService` variable instead of `app`, which is why service doesn't get registered in the `CalculatorService` module.

```
var CalculatorService = angular.module('CalculatorService', [])
app.service('Calculator', function () {
```

should be

```
var CalculatorService = angular.module('CalculatorService', [])
CalculatorService.service('Calculator', function () {
```

And in controller same thing repeated again, use `myApp` instead of `app` while registering controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['CalculatorService']);
myApp.controller('CalculatorController', function ($scope, Calculator) {
```

Comment: You are awesome. Question answered! Also in addition to that I updated my controller file from app.controller..... to myApp.controller. Thanks

Comment: @JerryGreen Glad to help you.Thanks :)